# Trying to determine if an S3 path exists in code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

So I am creating a glue job and part of it is to check if a path exists in s3. Imagine I had a path like so:
s3://my-bucket/level0/level1/level2 (etc)

Using Variables:
varBucket = "my-bucket"
varKey = "level0/"

Then this code works like so:

```
import boto3

from botocore.errorfactory import ClientError

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')        
    try:
                s3.head_object(Bucket=varBucket, Key=varKey)
                print("Path Exists")
            except ClientError:
                print("Path Does Not Exist")
                pass
```

I get the Print Output of "Path Exists"
BUT if I change the Key to this:
varKey="level0/level1/"

Then I get the Print that "Path Does Not Exist" - even though I know it does. I can go there in s3.
Its almost as if I can only go 1 level deep with the key but as soon as I try going to the next level and beyond, an exception happens. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to know if the "path" exists? With S3, you don't need to worry about creating directories.

Comment: Because I am building up an array of daily partitions to use in a dataframe with a variable of "NumberOfDays" to go backwards. Sometimes a day is missing (when a previous script did not run) and when I pass the array into "spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet(*bucket_path_array)" if the path doesnt exist, then this fails

Answer (score 2):

There are no "directories" in S3, only prefixes.

If you have a file `s3://my-bucket/level0/level1/level2/file.dat`, there is no "directory" object by the name of `level0/level1/`.

You can use the list objects call with a `Prefix=` to filter objects whose key (e.g. `level0/level1/level2/file.dat`) starts with such a prefix, but trying to `HeadObject` or `GetObject` on a prefix will not work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I got something working - maybe quite clunky but tested to work OK:

```
        for my_bucket_object in s3.Bucket(varBucket).objects.filter(Prefix=varKey):
        if varKey in my_bucket_object.key:
            ##Do Stuff
            break
```

Basically if the key exists in the bucket, it will DoStuff. In my case add the full s3 URI to an array for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Directories magically appear in S3 if there are files in that path. They then magically disappear if there are no files there.

If you want to know if they 'exist', then call:

```
list_objects(Bucket='your-bucket', Delimiter='/')
```

and look at the list of `CommonPrefixes` that are returned. They are the equivalent of directories.

To see directories at a deeper level, also specify a `Prefix`, eg:

```
list_objects(Bucket='your-bucket', Delimiter='/', Prefix='level0/level1/')
```